# CakePHP How can make global variable for button value

Tags: global-variables, cakephp-1.3

As you read this title maybe you thought that has many Threads like that but in my situation:

I want to define many variables content the name of the button or table fields...

For example: I have login page. So now I want control the value of button "Login" in one file.

The original:

```
echo $this->Form->end('Login'); //Static value name
```

My way:

```
echo $this->Form->end($btnlogin); //Depend on $btnlogin's values.
```

The **$btnlogin** will be define in "some where" it like

```
$btnlogin = "Login";
$btnregister = "Register"
$btnedit = "Edit"
...
```

So, in this way when I want to change the name of the button I can go to file and change it. I don't have to edit the source code inside. This way like properties file in Java.

Have anyone can suggest for me the way to do. I tried to make helper file but I can call the following variables which I have said. Please help ! Thank for reading.

---

**UPDATED:**
I found the solution for myself. We use the **Configure Class** like

Assigned:

```
Configure::write('Variable','ABC, DEF, GHI.');
```

Read:

```
Configure::read('Variable');
```

Source Book: [Configure Class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#configure-class)

So now my code will be:

```
//Assigned: code on file app/config/bootstrap.php
Configure::write('form','loginbtn'=>'LoginABC');

//On app/view/View.ctp
...
echo $this->Form->end(Configure::read('form.loginbtn'));
...
//Display will be
<input type="submit" value="LoginABC"/>
```

Comment: either answer the question yourself (posting it as an answer and accepting it) or delete it. I believe this may help someone, so edit your question removing your solution (just leave the question), answer it, and when the system lets you, accept it. Thx

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your mention. please show me how.

Comment: answer your question copy-pasting the update you did in the box below, and post it with "post your answer", and then after a day, accept your answer. Delete the update from the question itself